# Puppeteer looping of element handles not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have written a function in a separate class to enter text in all the element handles of the array of element handles

```
public async enterAllElementText(elements: ElementHandle[], text: string): Promise<any> {
    try {

        const texts = await elements.map(async (element: ElementHandle) => {
            await element.focus();
            await element.type('');
            await element.type(text);
            await this.enterKeys('Enter');
            await this.page.waitFor(500);
        });
        await Promise.all(texts);
    } catch (Exception) {
        console.error(chalk.red('\nFailed to enter Text!' + '\n' + Exception.toString()) + '\n');
        process.exit(0);

    }
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```
(async() => {

const texts = await page.$$(locators.texts);

await classInstance.enterAllElementText(texts, 'someText');
console.log('All texts entered!');

})();
```

But somehow it fails to execute as expected, I know this is an issue with **promise execution** as the `console` statement always gets executed first! What am I doing wrong here?

I also know that `map` & `for of` should be used with async & awaits for parallel and sequential execution of async functions respectively!